# C#: GridView, Row-By-Row Operations

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view displaying the messages a user has. Each message the user has is being marked whether it has been read or unread as a bit in my database table.

Is there a way how I can change the style of certain rows in my grid view according to whether the messages are read or unread?  I wish to display the whole row with an unread message in bold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to use the `RowDataBound` event for such a task.  Here is an example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" >
...
</asp:GridView>
```

.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // searching through the rows
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        bool isnew = (bool)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "IsNew");
        if ( isnew ) e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#FAF7DA"); // is a "new" row
    }
}
```

---

*Reference: http://blog.devexperience.net/en/5/Change_background_color_of_GridView's_Rows.aspx*

Comment: Hot dang! That was quick, I was only half way through typing up the same answer. ;)